# Can anyone help me explain why the code are different results

Tags: minizinc

I have  a  code sample  below , Can someone help me explain why the results are different

```
int : m=3; 
int : n=2; 
array[1..m,1..n] of int: va=[|1,2|
                              3,4|
                              5,6|];
array [1..m,1..n] of var int : val;
constraint forall(i in 1..m,j in 1..n )( i<2->val[i,j]=va[i,j]+1 );
constraint forall(i in 1..m,j in 1..n )( i>=2->val[i,j]=va[i,j]+3 );
output [ show(val) ];
```

```
int : m=3;
int : n=2; 
array[1..m,1..n] of int: va=[|1,2|
                              3,4|
                              5,6|];
array [1..m,1..n] of var int : val;

constraint forall(i in 1..m,j in 1..n )( i>=2->val[i,j]=va[i,j]+3 /\ i<2->val[i,j]=va[i,j]+1 );

output [ show(val) ];
```

if i can write this logic in one constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second model the two implications (`->`) and the conjunction (`/\`) bind different then using two `constraint` sections.

The following give the same result as model 1. Note the parenthesis around the implications:

```
int : m=3;
int : n=2; 
array[1..m,1..n] of int: va=[|1,2|
                              3,4|
                              5,6|];
array [1..m,1..n] of var int : val;

constraint forall(i in 1..m,j in 1..n )( (i>=2->val[i,j]=va[i,j]+3) /\
                                         (i<2->val[i,j]=va[i,j]+1) );

output [ show(val) ];
```

Now both models outputs:

```
[2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]
----------
==========
```